# NestJs - Single Model work with Different Database

Tags: database, mongodb, connection, nestjs

We have databases like the below image.

In Application, Once a new company registers a new database created for the company. Consider there might be multiple schemas.

Schemas would be the same for all company.

I am new to NestJS. Currently, we are managing this scenario using function call we pass database name it will create a new connection with DB using mongoose and iterate all defined models in from the database and create an object which used by application-wide.

Now, We need a new level of development. we choose NestJs.

**How can we deal with this kind of technique with nestjs?**

What should be a design pattern for this kind of flow?

How we will deal with Email for the registered company?

[image]

Comment: Did you manage to implement such architecture?

Comment: @learner Yes, Same architecture implemented in nodejs application and working since 4 years. Now planning to move in OOP world but this requirement not fit in NestJS. We have master DB which have copany details and copany can login and start working on that each copany have million of transaction.

Comment: How you connect to mongoose for different connections? Do you use nestjs mongoose module?

Comment: @learner I want to know trick how to connect multiple database using NestJS